# Springboot How modify list in an entity before send response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**How modify a list in an entity before send it?**

Explanations:

I have a Building entity which contain a list of Flat:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "building")
public class Building {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Flat> flats;
}
```

I also have User object, with a role: Manager or Commercial. Manager can see all Flats, but Commercial can see only those he created.

Now I need a endpoint to find a Building:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/building")
public class BuildingController {
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Building getBuildingById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        return buildingService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

But in this case, all Flats own by this Building are send, even if the user is Commercial. **How can I modify the list of flat to send only the good ones?**

Comment: Create a DTO don't modify the entity (as this might lead to an unwanted update in the database as you modify the entity). Create a DTO, copy and filter the data needed.

Comment: You will have to implement that, you can create the logic at your BuildService class to build a query that if the User is a Commercial one only fetch only the flats where the id of the flat creator is equal to the user id.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand thanks. But can i still use another Building object, and set the wanted flat list? i won't modify until i save it right?

Comment: @Cλstor i was thinking to something like this first, but i don't even know what the query looks like. Is it possible to query all Building object but not all Flats own by this building??

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme Yes, it is! Take a look at this [JPQL Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) It will be something like: 

SELECT * FROM Buildings b JOIN Flats f ON f.building_id = b.id AND f.user_id = ? WHERE building_id = ? , it's not exact, but you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found was to use Data Transfer Object (DTO). When I get an entity from database, I create a DTO and fill it with only wanted informations before send it. Here is an exemple of BuildingDto.java :

```
public class BuildingDto implements Serializable {
    ...
    private List<FlatDto> flats;
    private List<FlatUnauthorizedDto> flatsUnauthorized;

    // Constructors + getters + setters
}
```

Comment: Never send the entity directly. For example, If the user entity is transferred, password will be also transferred. Please use DTO objects once you leave the service layer. Pass the entity to the constructor of DTO to create corresponding object

Comment: Yes, I understood it and it's exactly what I give as solution :)